# cant download files in laravel in production

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to download a file in laravel. It works fine in localhost but not in production. The file path is ok. but the problem is when i am trying to download it. It gives an error saying the file doesnt exist. Below is my code. please help. thanks in advance

```
    public function getGo(Request $request){

    $file=asset('storage/source/hey.png');

    return response()->file($file);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the permission of file and is file exist in your production environment ? Is this image or pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code?. I think below code would be helpful.

```
public function getGo(Request $request){

    $file=storage_path('source/hey.png');

    return response()->file($file);
}
```

Comment: May i know the error you are getting? What is the permission given to storage folder and owner and group for that folder?

Comment: the source folder permission is 755. the error is file http://mysitelink/storage/source/hey.png does not exist

Comment: Have you deployed this application in shared hosting? Do they have any file extension restriction?